# How to protect individual table cells in Word for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working with Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac.

I have an assignment template for my students. I want them to fill in some cells of the table. Other cells are provided. How can I make it so my provided values are not editable? For example:

```
        Col 1.       Col2.      Col3.
Row 1.   100
Row 2.                0.5
Row 3.                0.1
```

In this table, I have provided values for cells (1,1), (2,2), and (3,2). I want my students to fill in the other values. How can I make it so they can't delete or modify the values 100, 0.5, and 0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. You can only protect the whole document or by Sections within the document. You cannot restrict editing by table cell.